# Django 1.7 and smart, deep, filtered aggregations

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm using Django 1.7 and I'm trying to seize the advantages of new features in the ORM.

Assume I have:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    answer1 = models.CharField(...)
    answer2 = models.CharField(...)
    answer3 = models.CharField(...)
    right = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(...) #choices=1, 2, or 3

class Session(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="games")

class RightAnswerManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        super(RightAnswerManager, self).get_queryset().filter(answer=models.F('question__right'))

class AnsweredQuestion(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, related_name="questions")
    question models.ForeignKey(Question, ...)
    answer = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(...) #1, 2, 3, or None if not yet ans.

    objects = models.Manager()
    right = RightAnswerManager()
```

I know I can do:

```
Session.objects.prefetch_related('questions')
```

And get the sessions with the questions.

Also I can do:

```
Session.objects.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('questions', queryset=AnsweredQuestion.right.all(), to_attr='answered'))
```

And get the sessions with the list of questions that were actually answered and right.

**BUT** I cannot do aggregation over those, to get -e.g.- the count of elements instead:

```
Session.objects.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('questions', queryset=AnsweredQuestion.right.all(), to_attr='answered')).annotate(total_right=models.Count('answered'))
```

since `answered` is not a real field:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'rightones' into field. Choices are: id, name, sessions
```

This is only a sample, since there are a lot of fields in my models I never included. However the idea is clear: I cannot aggregate over created attributes.

Is there a way **without falling to raw** to respond to the following question?

```
Get each user annotated with their "points".
A user may play any amount of sessions.
In each session it gets many questions to answer.
For each right answer, a point is earned.
```

In RAW SQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT user.*, COUNT(answeredquestion.id)
FROM user
LEFT OUTER JOIN session ON (session.user_id = user.id)
INNER JOIN answeredquestion ON (answeredquestion.session_id = session.id)
INNER JOIN question ON (answeredquestion.question_id = question.id)
WHERE answeredquestion.answer = question.right
GROUP BY user.id
```

Or something like that (since there's a functional dependency in the grouping field, I would collect the user data and count the related answeredquestions, assuming the condition passes). So RAW queries are not an option for me.

The idea is to get the users with the total points.

My question can be responded in one of two ways (or both).

- Is there a way to perform the same query (actually I never tested this exact query; It's here to present the idea) with the ORM in Django 1.7, somehow given the Prefetch or manager selection on related/inverse FK fields? **Iteration is not allowed here** (I'd have a quadratic version of the N+1 problem!).
- Is there any django package which somehow does this? Perhaps doing an abstraction of RAW calls, provided by 3rd party. **this is because I will have many queries like this one**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe using prefetch gets you any gain in this situation. Generally prefetch_related and select_related are used when looping through a filterset and accessing a related object for each. By doing the annotate in the initial query I believe django will take of that optimization for you.

For the question "Get each user annotated with their "points" try this query:

```
Player.objects.annotate(total_right=models.Count('games__questions__right'))
```